# Installation issue in MSI GT780DX, screen freezes

Tags: nvidia, msi

Configuration: i7 2670, Nvidia GTX 570, 1920X1080, 17.3", HDD 750GB, RAM 12 GB, trying to install under Windows 7, 64bit. Used 64 bit Ubuntu for installation, both 12.04 and 11.04, none worked, in 12, Display Problem, and 11 freezes, both after installation, while booting.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue until I've blacklisted the nouveau driver
http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-the-msi-gt780dx/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.